# How to fix "NULL is not a valid DataTable." - Laravel Lavacharts

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have my data in an array and I'm trying to display the information in a Lavacharts Donut Chart, I've hit a wall since I'm not sure why it is erroring out, when I dump the variable ($counted_heroes) it looks fine but I'm not an expert with arrays.

I have googled the error but it only lead to a github issues page where it was unfortunately never resolved, I've looked at the Laravel "arguments" section of the error to see why it is erroring, it looks fine from my perspective with no empty values.

```
function index()
{
    $heroes = \Lava::DataTable();
    $heroes = DB::table('replays')->leftJoin('heroes', 'heroes.id', '=', 'replays.hero_id')->select(DB::raw('replays.hero_id as hero_id, heroes.hero_name as hero_name'))->get()->toArray();
    foreach($heroes as & $hero) {
        $hero = ['hero' => $hero->hero_name, $hero->hero_id, ];
    }

    $counted_heroes = array_count_values(array_column($heroes, 'hero'));
    \Lava::DonutChart('Heroes', $counted_heroes, ['title' => 'Heroes Played']);
    return view('public.stats', compact('lava'));
}
```

The expected outcome of this would be that the array is accepted by the Lavachart and the data is displayed, instead of this unfortunate error.

Any help would be most appreciated! <3

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a lavachart expert, but I think it's because `$counted_heroes` isn't a lava datatable, just an array. `DonutChart` probably expects a Lava::Datatable instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`compact()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) assumes that `$compact` variable is defined before.

You didn't defined it inside your `index()` method.

Try `return view('public.stats', compact('heroes'));`, your view is expecting not an array, but a certain library object, as it was mentioned by [ourmandave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794900/how-to-fix-null-is-not-a-valid-datatable-laravel-lavacharts/55795151#comment98259230_55794900).
Note, that you have to replace `lava` to `heroes` in your view than.